# Retrieve XML Data to use webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

What I am trying to do:

- Get location based off of IP (Done)
- Use the City and Country code to use openweather's API (Done)
- Read the XML into my webpage so that I can display the "Temperature" field.

This is my first venture into using XML in webpages, and I've tried for 3 days now with no success. I have searched google and stackoverflow, and have tried many things so far, including SimpleXMLElement, with no luck.

What I currently have on my page is just a generated link to the XML sheet for your location.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var country = geoip_country_code();
    var city = geoip_city();
    document.write('<a href="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + ',' + country + '&mode=xml&units=metric">Link text</a>');
</script>
```

How am I able to display the text from the required field on my page?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to change the API call to return JSON, in which case you could then use this code, the temps are stored in temp, temp_min and temp_max.

```
var country = geoip_country_code();
var city = geoip_city();

$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + ',' + country + '&mode=json&units=metric', function( json ) {
    var temp = json.main.temp;
    var temp_min = json.main.temp_min;
    var temp_max = json.main.temp_max;

    document.write( 'Temp: ' + temp + '<br>');
    document.write( 'Temp Min: ' + temp_min + '<br>');
    document.write( 'Temp Max: ' + temp_max + '<br>');
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question, when I have that code in my page, it replaces all content with a white background and just those values. I tried placing the "document.write" lines else where in my page but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript library to convert the xml into a javascript object - one such library is called xml2json, it works as a jQuery plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

Then you can simply do:

```
var xmlObject;

$.ajax({
    url: url_of_xml,
    success: function(data) {
        xmlObject = $.xml2json(data);
    }
});
```

Then you just need to place the data on your page. The object in my example is faked, but it gives you the idea:

```
// put this line in the success callback of your ajax call
// after you create the xmlObject
$('#temp').html(xmlObject.weather.temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the `temperature` you get the XML, and read one of the three temperature attributes from the XML returned:

```
 $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + ',' + country + '&mode=xml&units=metric", function(xml) {
 avg = $(xml).find("temperature").attr("value"));
 max = $(xml).find("temperature").attr("max"));
 min = $(xml).find("temperature").attr("min"));
```

(using JQuery)